Error when trying to get variables from a csv file using RobotFramework
I used to work with pycharm but I need to change to vscode.
I migrate the tests I had creatd on Pycharm and one of them is getting Unexpected argument error on the ${description} variable.
Can you figure what wrong?
Thanks.
Here's the code:
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Package 2.1
Library          SeleniumLibrary
Library          DataDriver    file=../../Automated Tests/Provisioning Process/resources/package2.1_data.csv    dialect=excel     encoding=utf-8
Resource         ../../custom_code/customized_keywords.robot
Resource         ../../Provisioning Process/resources/login.robot
Resource         ../../Provisioning Process/resources/sharepoint.robot
Resource         ../../Provisioning Process/resources/teams.robot
Test Setup       Open SPO Site    ${tenant_url}    Chrome
Test Template    Create And Approve A New Request
Test Teardown    Close Browser


*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 473511: Provision a new Teams Group: ${teams_group_name}
    [Documentation]    *Objective:* Request and approve a new Teams Group in multiple iterations
    ...                *Test Case URL:* https://tfs.ext.icrc.org/ICRCCollection/Digital%20Workplace/_testPlans/define?planId=412018&suiteId=473508
    ...                *Prerequisites:* Define iteration to be executed in append package2.1_data.csv file
    Create And Approve A New Request    ${teams_group_name}    ${sensitivity_label}     ${space_type}    ${justification}    ${description}


*** Keywords ***
Create And Approve A New Request
    [Tags]    IN PROGRESS
    [Arguments]    ${teams_group_name}    ${sensitivity_label}    ${space_type}    ${justification}    ${description}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${teams_request_element}
    # Access teams request page
    Wait Until Element Is Visible And Click    ${teams_request_element}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${title_teams_request_page}
    # open request form
    Wait Until Button Is Visible And Click    ${new_request_btn}
    Wait Until Iframe Is Visible And Select Frame    ${request_form_iframe1}
    Wait Until Iframe Is Visible And Select Frame    ${request_form_iframe2}
    # Fill request from
    Wait Until Element Is Visible And Input Text    ${teams_groups_name_input}    ${teams_group_name}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible And Input Text    ${description_input}    ${description}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible And Click    ${type_of_space_input}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible And Click    //span[@class='itemTemplateLabel_dqr75c' and contains(text(), '${space_type}')]
    Wait Until Element Is Visible And Input Text    ${justification_input}    ${justification}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible And Click    ${owners_element}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${owners_input}
    Input Text    ${owners_input}    jsilva
    Wait Until Element Is Visible And Click    ${jsilva_list_element}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible And Click    ${members_element}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${members_input}
    Input Text    ${members_input}    spierre
    Wait Until Element Is Visible And Click    ${seb_list_element}
    Double Click Element    ${remove_src_value}
    Input Text    ${members_input}    ibozo
    Wait Until Element Is Visible And Click    ${ivan_list_element}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible And Click    ${sensitivity_input}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible And Click    //span[@class='itemTemplateLabel_dqr75c' and contains(text(), '${sensitivity_label}')]
    Capture Page Screenshot
    Unselect Frame
    # Submit
    Wait Until Button Is Visible And Click    ${form_save_btn}
    Wait Until Element Is Not Visible    ${form_save_btn}
    Log    Request Form: EXECUTED
    Unselect Frame

csv file:
***Test Cases***;${teams_group_name};${sensitivity_label};${space_type};${justification};${description}
Case1;Public with Default template;Public;Default template;Automated testing;All Approve
Case 2;Public without L2 IM validation;Public;Validator and L2 Apps Admin;Automated testing;Skips L2 IM validation

I tried to leave the test case empty and failed.
Also, change the csv file location and it also failed.

Well I only managed to get the data, ignoring the Arguments and processing them directly.
Note that I had to use the dialect=Excel-EU because data is semi-column separated.
See this minimal functional example:
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Package 2.1
Test Setup        Open Browser    http://example.com    headlessfirefox
Test Teardown     Close Browser
Test Template     Create And Approve A New Request
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           DataDriver    file=test_data_driver.csv    dialect=Excel-EU    encoding=utf-8

*** Test Cases ***
Test None
    No Operation

*** Keywords ***
Create And Approve A New Request
    [Tags]    IN PROGRESS
    Set Test Variable    \${teams_group_name}    ${DataDriver_TEST_DATA['arguments']['\${teams_group_name}']}
    Set Test Variable    \${sensitivity_label}    ${DataDriver_TEST_DATA['arguments']['\${sensitivity_label}']}
    Set Test Variable    \${space_type}    ${DataDriver_TEST_DATA['arguments']['\${space_type}']}
    Set Test Variable    \${justification}    ${DataDriver_TEST_DATA['arguments']['\${justification}']}
    Set Test Variable    \${description}    ${DataDriver_TEST_DATA['arguments']['\${description}']}
    Log Many    ${teams_group_name}    ${sensitivity_label}    ${space_type}    ${justification}    ${description}    console=True
    Capture Page Screenshot

And here the result:


The weird thing is the keywork needs 5 arguments but in the Test Cases it only request 4.
